# Images are overlapping the navigation bar when I hover over the images

Tags: html, css

I created a website which has a navigation bar. When I scroll and hover over the images, they are overlapping on the navigation bar as you can see [on my website here](https://siddharthmagadum16.github.io/project-start/) or in the following image:

[image: overlapping image]

I tried to shift the hover code at the top (according to the less priority), but it didn't work.

I want the image to be tilted when hovered, but under the navigation bar.

Can anyone tell how to fix this, please?

The below is the code of CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
    margin: auto 0;
}
.zone {
    /* padding:30px 50px; */
    /* margin:40px 60px; */
    cursor:pointer;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    color:rgb(252, 251, 253);
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:5px solid rgba(0, 58, 8, 0.856);
    /* transition: all 0.3s linear; */
}
/* NAV BAR */
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:  0;
}

li {
    padding: 20px;
}
li:hover {
    box-shadow: yellowgreen;
}
a {
    color: #24011f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav li:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .main-nav {
        padding: none;
        font-size: 0.4em;
    }
}
/* COVER */
.container {
    display: flex;
    /* width: auto; */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50vh;
}
/* petrify */
.cover {
    width: 20rem;
}

/* GRID-wrapper */
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;    
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px,auto));
    /* shape-outside: ellipse(45%);  */
    /* color: #febf04; */
}
.box > img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
.box {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.box:hover {
    transform: rotate(8deg);
    /* transition: ; */
    mask-position: center;
    
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0,0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15)     0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15)           0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0..15)        0px -10px 20px;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100% ;
    top: 0rem;
}
footer {                        /* footer */
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/****************************************************************************
*  Green Background
**********************************************************************/
.green{
    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Red Background
**********************************************************************/
.red{
    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Yellow Background
**********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Blue Background
**********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="zone blue sticky">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container zone">
      <img class="cover" src="./img/undraw.png" alt="image9">
    </div>
    <div class="zone blue grid-wrapper">
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/data_storage_2_2.png" alt="image1"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/desktop_analytics_2.png" alt="image2"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/files_2.png" alt="image3"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/monitor_coding_2.png" alt="image4"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/monitor_settings_2.png" alt="image5"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/server_2_2.png" alt="image6"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/server_3.png" alt="image7"></div>
      <div class="box zone"><img src="./img/server_safe_2.png" alt="image8"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="zone yellow">Zero => Mastery</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the z-index property to change how the browser will handle overlapping when it occurs. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

In this case you can change the z-index of your 'sticky' css class to get the desired behaviour.

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0rem;
    z-index: 100;
}
```